# Accessing a sharepoint xlsx programmatically through R

Tags: r, sharepoint, xlsx

I am currently trying to access a xlsx file present in company sharepoint drive

```r
URL - https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/cqa/xxxx/_layouts/15/doc2.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BFxxx390-B71D-4C71-B252-6E3DCA8E9FDA%7D&file=Updated%20LXXal%20Reqxxxxents%20for%20XXXXX%20XXXX%20Actixxxx.xlsx&action=default&mobileredirect=true&cid=0abe8bcd-c785-4c14-a9f3-263e8e806aa6
```

I read multiple links but none of them seem to work.
Tried using `httr::GET`

```r
require(httr)
url <- "above url"
r <- GET(url, authenticate("amit.sahoo@xxxx.com","password"))
```

But getting the below error response:

```r
  Date: 2022-04-08 13:07
  Status: 403
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
  Size: 13 B
```

Tried using `Microsoft365R::get_sharepoint_site("above url")` but it shows "Need admin approval".

Is there any other direct way to read the file through R in a dataframe. Any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to access a xlsx file in a sharepoint with the following code :

```
library(readxl)
url <- "https://sharepoint.mycompany.ca/teams/report/file.xlsx"
download.file(url = url, destfile = "D:/file.xlsx", mode = "wb")
read_excel("D:/file.xlsx")
```